# How to see the length of selected text in gedit?

Tags: 22.04, gedit, plugins, gnome-text-editor

How can I see the length of selected text in gedit like this example image?

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.

[image: screenshot showing example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this (crudely) using the External Tools plugin. First enable the plugin:
[image: Preferences->Plugins->External Tools (check the checkbox)]

Then create the following external tool with the code

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
text = sys.stdin.read()
print(len(text))
```

[image: set "Save" to "nothing", "input" to "current selection", and "output" to "display in bottom pane"]

Then add a shortcut key of your choice. Now you can select some text, press the keybind, and get a character count of your selection in a popup at the bottom of your window.

(You can also go to (menu)->Tools->Document Statistics, but this is not very keyboard-friendly.)

You could probably also hack something together using the python console, or even write a bespoke plugin for this. With that said, I would probably just use a more customizable editor. Gedit is more meant for when you just need a text editor now and nothing else.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and comments